# Why Sphinx grouping so quickly?

Tags: mongodb, sphinx

We have a database of 60 million documents. Our challenge is to perform a similar query "SELECT entity_id, min(price) as min_price FROM entities WHERE param1 = 1 and param2 = 2 GROUP BY entity_id ORDER BY min_price LIMIT 100;" During the investigation, we concluded that query  relatively database (mysql, mongo) is too expensive (even if you do it in perfect conditions with an index). For them it is no less than 10 seconds. If you do not use indexes, the account goes on a minute. Opposite this Sphinx performs a similar request for a split second. And it has no relation to the full-text search! how it does it?

Comment: I would suspect it is the way that inverse text indexes are built up, they are pre-grouped by the search fields

Comment: but he still does aggregation within each grouping!

Comment: and it is with 10 different (for each query) filter options